# Nested Wrapper to Find How To Find HTML Element Exists?

Tags: html, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I currently am writing a unit test where I am trying to use wrapper.find to find a child HTML element

I tried using wrapper.find(element).find(element).exists()).toBe(true); however the result always returns false. When I tried to find each element separately, the test returned true.

What I am testing:

```
if(brand === Nike) {
    <div className="test"> 
       <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
} else {
   <div className="test"></div>
}
```

The current test I have (testing that the brand is Nike):
`expect(wrapper.find('.test').find('p').exists()).toBe(true);`

I have defined the wrapper previously (like stated, separately the test works, it's when I try a nested find that it doesn't)

I expect the output to return true since the brand is equal to Nike.. however it returns false always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that a simpler solution is:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.test p')).not.toBeUndefined();
```

The nested finds aren't necessary.

Also, the brand check, is Nike an element? If it's a string you should be checking for it as a string:

```
if (brand === 'Nike') { ...
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This was a huge help and the test works;  also yes that was a mistake when writing the question; Nike is actually a string